# How to change the css styling of only those columns in a table which contains a decimal point

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table, css-selectors

I have a division question which I'm displaying in a table. Each digit is stored in a "**td**". I want to reduce the width and remove all the padding of the "**td**" which contains the "**decimal point**". But I'm unable to change that particular td without changing the stylings of rest of the columns.

*Please note that* - I cannot use an ID or a class on the element because of my complex code structure.
**Only apply new styles to the nth child if it contains decimal point anywhere in the table.**

[image]

So, I'm trying to do it in the below manner:

```
tbody>tr>:nth-child(7){
      width:2px !important;
      padding: 0px !important;
      column-width: 8px !important;
}
```

The above code works fine but it will cause issue if the decimal point is placed anywhere other than the position/child "7" (i.e, in a different column of the divisor or divident).

Another way - not working at all!!!! :-

```
div[title~="`.`"] {
       width: 12px !important;
       padding: 0px !important;
       column-width: 5px !important;
}
```

One more way - no styles are getting applied !!!! :-

```
   tbody>tr>td {
       div.decimalPoint {
         width:2px !important;
         padding: 0px !important;
         column-width: 8px !important;
       }
   }
```

Please help me find a workaround for this in which I can check whichever "td" contains the **decimal point** should have 0 padding and reduced width.

Comment: Please include your HTML.

Comment: If you use a class like `.decimalPoint` it should work with a rule like `td .decimalPoint { .. }` with a space between the tag and class. No `!important` required. Show a [reprex] as requested before so we can verify where you are going off track in your code.

Comment: If you want to style based on content you’ll need JavaScript.